# The given key was not present in the dictionary when trying to remove

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I've looked through various posts with similar issues to the one I'm facing, but can't seem to pinpoint what the issue could be!

I'll give a bit of background as to what my process does...

I have a listview which in this example, contains 4 rows. Two of the key fields in that listview are column 0 and column 1, so I concat these together to generate a key and add them to a list, which I've chosed a Dictionary(Of String, Integer) to hold the data.

Once this dictionary is loaded up with the items, a background worker is kicked off that loops through the dictionary items and works them. It does them one at a time, but the main reason is so the application can still be used while its working and more items can be added to the listview which the background worker will pick up automatically while looping through (it only works one item at a time though).

When the background worker has finished working that item, it will remove the item from the Dictionary using the variable.remove(key) function, which is where I am having the problem. When I try and remove an item from the Dictionary, I'm getting the message "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

My broken down code is as follows...

```
Dim DevWorker_Item As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
Dim WhichKeyUsing As String

.... Process here adds items to the DevWorker_Item variable which gives me the following keys and values...
TABLE_A   4023
TABLE_B   1010
TABLE_C   42
TABLE_D   2020

Do Until DevWorker_Item.Count = 0
  WhichKeyUsing = DevWorker_Item.Keys.First()

  ... Do work now on that Key writing data to file etc ...

  If DevWorker_Item.ContainsKey(WhichKeyUsing) Then
    DevWorker_Item.Remove(WhichKeyUsing)
  End If

Loop
```

Am I missing something, I've done a test to see if the Dictionary as the key in there before removing, but at the DevWorker_Item.Remove(WhichKeyUsing) I get the error.

Thanks

Comment: If you have multiple threads modifying the dictionary, you may want to look into the `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` class which is thread safe.

Comment: According to the documentation you should not get any error even if the key is not present in dictionary. The only way the Remove method throws error is when key being removed is `Nothing`. Something else somewhere seems to be bad in your code. What happens if you put a breakpoint on that line and step thru line by line?

Comment: See this... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabs04ac(v=vs.110).aspx